# CakePHP Find Related Data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

My Gallery model is related to my image model, but when I retrive images from galleries_controller I cant see any result and instead see this error:

**Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP\views\galleries\view.ctp, line 35]**

Here is the code from my controller action:

```
    function view($id = null) {
            if (!$id) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid gallery', true));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->set('gallery', $this->Gallery->read(null,$id));
 $this->Gallery->Image->find('all',array('conditions' => array('Image.gallery_id'=> $id)));
             $this->set('images', $images);

        }
```

This is the loop I have in my galleries/view to iterate through the array.

```
<?php

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($images['Image'] as $image):
            $class = null;
            if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
                $class = ' class="altrow"';
            }
        ?>
        <tr<?php echo $class;?>>
            <td><?php $image['id'] ;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $image['name'];?></td>
            <!--<td><?php echo $image['img_file'];?></td>-->

            <td><?php  echo $html->image('uploads' . DS . 'images' . DS . $image['img_file'], array('alt' => 'Gallery Image')); ?></td>

        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't setting anything with your set. Your find is being executed and then not stored in a variable. Furthermore, your view loop is iterating through incorrectly.

Change your controller to:

```
  function view($id = null) {
            if (!$id) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid gallery', true));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->set('gallery', $this->Gallery->read(null,$id));
 $images = $this->Gallery->Image->find('all',array('conditions' => array('Image.gallery_id'=> $id)));
             $this->set('images', $images);
        }
```

And your view code to:

```
<?php

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($images as $image):
            $class = null;
            if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
                $class = ' class="altrow"';
            }
        ?>
        <tr<?php echo $class;?>>
            <td><?php $image['Image']['id'] ;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $image['Image']['name'];?></td>
            <!--<td><?php echo $image['Image']['img_file'];?></td>-->

            <td><?php  echo $html->image('uploads' . DS . 'images' . DS . $image['Image']['img_file'], array('alt' => 'Gallery Image')); ?></td>

        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

That having been said, since all you want to do is pull in associated images when a gallery is viewed, you should look into setting up your model associations and then doing a find on your gallery that will include the images you want like so:

```
$this->set('gallery',$this->Gallery->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Gallery.id' => $id), 'recursive' => 1));
```

If the above don't work, then there is something misconfigured in your models. Please post your model code so we can investigate further.